# Presenting a view controller turns iPhone's orientation to portrait

Tags: iphone, ios, orientation

I am presenting a view controller that plays video in it.

[image]

When I tap to a button, the video player view is initiated from storyboard with this code:

```
_moviePlayer = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"videoPlayerController"];
[_moviePlayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[_moviePlayer playMoviesForItems:shopItems];
[self presentViewController:_moviePlayer animated:NO completion:^{
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectZero animated:YES];
}];
```

But orientation turns to portrait like this:

[image]

I wrote code below but doesn't work:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:      (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
 {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
 }


-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

There is no problem with iPad. Problem is with iPhone.

Updated:

Supported Orientations are:

[image]

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please put below method as well..My be this will help you

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Code is in viewDidLoad

Comment: _moviePlayer = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"videoPlayerController"];
[_moviePlayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[_moviePlayer playMoviesForItems:shopItems];
[self presentViewController:_moviePlayer animated:NO completion:^{
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectZero animated:YES];

Comment: This code is in action. -(void)playMoviesForItems:(NSArray *)shopItems;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38412/discussion-between-dipen-chudasama-and-burak)

Answer (score 0):

Try applying transform and scaling it

```
CGAffineTransform aTransform =CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
currentTransform=  CGAffineTransformConcat(aTransform, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation method.Hope it will help.

Comment: what all are the orientation you have given in project file?